# Improved CPQ Quote Preview Process

Tags: approval-process, cpq, quote

Our company has NS with SF and CPQ on the front-end.  I'm one of the team members responsible for approving quotes.  When I receive those emails, there is a link that takes me to the opportunity, but it takes 5 clicks to preview the quote.

In a perfect world, I want the link to take me to the preview itself.

Is there a way to include a more poignant link where it takes me to the PREVIEW, instead of clicking 5 times to see what I'm supposed to approve?